# How to manually move rows from one database to the next?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases on the same server. One db is newer than the other and has had its schema modified quite a bit. I want to transfer data from a table in the old db to a table in the new db but I need total control over the process so I can mold the old data to fit the new schema.

```
[NewDB].[dbo].[Aliases]

[OldDB].[Terminal].[Alias]
```

I'm not very adept at SQL yet. Is there a way I can loop through all the records in the old table and then on each iteration of the loop craft a custom insert statement for the new table?

Comment: Why not just write one insert with columns listed?

Comment: never loop through records when transferring large amounts of data, you will be there for the rest of yoru life!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an INSERT SELECT statement.

```
INSERT INTO [NewDB].[dbo].[Aliases] 
SELECT columns
FROM [OldDB].[Terminal].[Alias]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=sql.100).aspx - derived table section
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Do it the same way as you would if both tables were in the same database.  Just fully qualify the names of the tables.  Example:

```
INSERT INTO [NewDB].[dbo].[Aliases] (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT LEFT(col1,3), col2, col3 FROM [OldDB].[Terminal].[Alias]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the data size you wish to transfer, you might want to consider using `BULK INSERT`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: This is not advisable on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO NEWDB..TABLENAME( *fieldlist* )
SELECT *fieldlist* FROM OLDDB..TABLENAME
```